# Selecionar várias tabelas ao mesmo tempo em SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho 5 tabelas no meu sistema:

```
pacientes - Primary key idPacientes
anamnese - foreggin key idPacientes
avaliacoes - foreggin key idPacientes
intervencao - foreggin key idPacientes
contrato - foreggin key idPacientes
```

A tabela `pacientes` tem a chave primária chamada `idPacientes`, as demais têm as chaves estrangeiras conectadas ao paciente.

Estou fazendo um relatório para quando eu terminar de cadastrar, fazer anamnese, avaliar, intervenir com o paciente e dar o seu contrato, eu puxar todas as informações que estão na `anamnese`, `avaliacoes`, `intervencao` e `contrato` do paciente.

Mas não sei como fazer um `select` disso. Meu professor me ajudou dando um exemplo, mas que só pega as informações do pacientes e da anamnese:

```
SELECT PAC., FIC.
FROM PACIENTES AS PAC INNER JOIN anamnese AS FIC ON PAC.idPacientes=FIC.idPacientes
where pac.idPacientes = '$id'
```

Aonde está escrito `PAC` e `FIC` são os apelidos das tabelas `pacientes` e `anamnese`. Quero ter a mesma coisa desse `SELECT`, mas incluindo o restante das tabelas.

Comment: Você quer criar uma consulta que retorne dados das 5 tabelas ao mesmo tempo, é isso? Eu não entendi o parágrafo final, pode reformular, por favor, para ficar mais claro? Informe também o banco de dados que está usando, na pergunta e nas tags.

Comment: Pedro, faça o teste usando a minha resposta e me diga se era isso que você desejava ok?

Comment: É realmente isso André, mas testei aqui e não foi deu esse error mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Answer (score 3):

Pode ler a [documentacao](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) sobre INNER JOIN e LEFT JOIN. 
Uma Ideia simples para juntar as tabelas sera algo como

```
Select * from Pacientes INNER JOIN anamnese ON anamnese.idPacientes == Pacientes.idPacientes
```

Nesse caso você retorna todos os pacientes que tiverem na tabela anamnese.
Para juntar mais tabelas seria o caso de adicionar outro inner join

```
Select * from Pacientes 
INNER JOIN anamnese ON anamnese.idPacientes == Pacientes.idPacientes 
INNER JOIN avaliação ON avaliação.idPacientes == Pacientes.idPacientes
```

Sempre deixando a tabela que tiver mais registros a esquerda do ON.
Na documentação existe muitas outras dicas que você deve levar em consideração.

Comment: Tem algum DBMS que usa `==` como operador de comparação? Seria legal colocar um link para a documentação que você menciona!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Pacientes pac
LEFT JOIN anamnese as ana ON ana.idPacientes = pac.idPacientes 
LEFT JOIN avaliacao as ava ON ava.idPacientes = pac.idPacientes 
LEFT JOIN intervenção as int ON int.idPacientes = pac.idPacientes 
LEFT JOIN Contratos as cont ON cont.idPacientes = pac.idPacientes
```

Lembrando que onde está o * você deve pôr os campos das tabelas, ex: pac.Nome, pac.Idade, int.AlgumaCoisa, cont.OutraCoisa.

Comment: No padrão ISO `int` é uma palavra reservada, no SQL Server não ([doc SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql)), então, dependendo de qual [DBMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system) estiver sendo usado, esse `int` como alias pode dar errado.

Comment: Verdade Pedro Gaspar, não percebi na hora. Lembrando que o nome da tabele á você quem define Pedro Lukas (bom se atentar a nomenclatura como citado pelo Pedro)..

Comment: Desculpem se eu não fui muito claro, mas eu respondi essa minha pergunta olhem lá em baixo, pfv

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja exibir todos os registros de cada tabela, você pode usar ( **.*** ) para extrair todos os dados de cada tabela relacionada do seguinte modo:

```
SELECT 
 Pacientes.*,
 Anamnese.*,
 Avaliação.*,
 Intervenção.*,
 Contratos.* 
FROM Pacientes
 JOIN Anamnese ON Pacientes.idPacientes = Anamnese.idPacientes
 JOIN Avaliacao ON Anamnese.idPacientes = Avaliacao.idPacientes
 JOIN Intervenção ON Anamnese.idPacientes = Intervenção.idPacientes
 JOIN Contratos ON Contratos.idPacientes = Intervenção.idPacientes
WHERE Pacientes.idPacientes = [Id do paciente que você deseja]
```

**Nota:** o **.*** trás todos os campos da tabela, porém, você pode adicionar as colunas desejadas caso você não queira trazer todos em algum momento posterior.

**Dica:** A dica que te dou é de criar tanto as tabelas quanto as colunas sem acentuação gráfica para melhor manutenção de seu projeto.

Comment: Eaí brother, é isso mesmo que eu quero, mas testei aqui aí apareceu isso Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC3001\TCC V3.0\relatorios\infopaciente.php on line 14

Comment: Esse erro deu na aplicação php ou direto no banco?

Comment: na aplicação php msm

Comment: Se eu passar o sistema pra você, tu da uma olhada?

Comment: Claro, estou aqui para ajudá-lo. Mas só me tira uma dúvida... Você já tentou executar este select no banco?

Comment: Sim, já consegui brother kk vlw ae

Comment: @PedroLukas o que era o problema?

Comment: Erro era de aspas kk

Comment: Ah, então o que mandei ajudou não é?